# Javascript отправка формы на email

Tags: javascript

Как получить данные формы на email?

Вот кусок кода:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  var form = $(this), 
      data = new Object(); 
  data.data3 = $('input[name=name]', form).val(); 
  data.data4 = $('input[name=phone]', form).val();
  data.country = $('select[name=country]', form).val();
  var str = JSON.stringify(data), 
      tmp = '';
  for(var i in str) {
    tmp += str.charCodeAt(i) + ' '; 
  }
  $.post('/index.php', {'pre' : 1, 'data': tmp}); 
  return true; 
});
```

Попробовал прикрутить файл index.php Почему не работает?

```
?php
function show_form()
{
?>

From = 'mail@test.ru'; // от кого, например электронный адрес вашего сайт
$mail->FromName = 'mail@test.ru'; // от кого, имя.
$mail->AddAddress('mail@test.ru', 'Имя'); // кому? Ваша почта, Имя
$mail->IsHTML(true); // формат письма HTML
$mail->Subject = "Тема письма"; // тема письма

// если есть файл, то прикрепляем его к письму

if(isset($_FILES['upl'])) {
if($_FILES['upl']['error'] == 0){
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['upl']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['upl']['name']);
}
}

$mail->Body = $mess;
// отправляем наше письмо
if (!$mail->Send()) die ('Mailer Error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo);
}

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) complete_mail();
else show_form();
?>
```

Comment: `tmp += str.charCodeAt(i) + ' ';` - Вот как надо шифровать данные! Учитесь!

Comment: Запрос отправляет данные из полей в обработчик `index.php` где , как раз и  должна происходить отправка

Comment: @Андрей напишите в вопросе как Вы пробовали, код Вашего index.php

Comment: а какую ошибку Вы получаете?

Comment: Ошибки не выдает, просто имейл не отправляет(